# How to turn off the screen from a docker container?

Tags: docker, x11

I have a docker container running with a GUI app on it. All is working well except when the app try to turn off the screen by pushing the following command to the system : `xset -display :0.0 dpms force off`

When this command reach the system, the docker container fail.

Here is the docker-compose.yml content for this container:

```
version: "3"

volumes:
  kiosk_vol:

services:
  func:
    image: docker.alatimier.fr/kiosk/func:snapshot
    restart: always
    environment:
      KIOSK_ID: ${KIOSK_ID}
      ADDR: ${ADDR}
      # For Linux host
      DISPLAY:
      # For OSX host, install socat and xquarts and create TCP bridge between the docker container and X11 window server :
      # socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
      #DISPLAY: docker.for.mac.localhost:0
    volumes:
    - kiosk_vol:/working_directory
    - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
    depends_on:
    - conf
    ipc: "host"
```

Would you have any idea why I can't turn off the host screen from the docker container ?

The host is on lubuntu 18.04, and I tested the command line to shut down the screen and it works fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out:

First thing is to edit the dockerfile to install the X utilities (without it, xset is not known in the docker container):

```
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y x11-xserver-utils
```

Then edit the docker-compose.yml in order to give access to the .Xauthority file and pass the display name:

```
version: "4"

volumes:
  kiosk_vol:

services:
  func:
    image: docker.alatimier.fr/kiosk/func:snapshot
    restart: always
    environment:
      KIOSK_ID: ${KIOSK_ID}
      ADDR: ${ADDR}
      # For Linux host
      DISPLAY: $DISPLAY
      # For OSX host, install socat and xquarts and create TCP bridge between the docker container and X11 window server :
      # socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:\"$DISPLAY\"
      #DISPLAY: docker.for.mac.localhost:0
    volumes:
    - kiosk_vol:/working_directory
    - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
    - $HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw
    depends_on:
    - conf
    ipc: "host"
```

Hope this help if someone have the same issue.